# JavaScript add decimal without using toFixed() method

Tags: javascript, integer, decimal

I've got some values that are appended with 00's for cents by PHP. I need to add a decimal point to them.

```
val = 10000 (needs to turn into 100.00);

val.toFixed(2) = 10000.00 (no bueno);

val.magic() = 100.00 (perf!)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `toFixed()`?

Comment: Didn't realize I could. Going to accept @Matthew's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(val/100).toFixed(2) = 100.00;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even consider that. Whoops. It's a Sunday here... still working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string value in cents, a simple regular expression can be used to insert a decimal point:

```
function addPoint(s) {
  return s.replace(/(\d\d)$/,'.$1');
}

var s = '1000';
alert(addPoint(s)); // 10.00
```